# Is it possible to build a firm connection between compound ratio and chain rule?

Tags: calculus, education, ratio

I am teaching the chain rule to a student in high school and was thinking about the possibility to justify the chain rule using (but not just by means of them) the cancellation process (which I am aware it is not a totally correct way to see it). I mean if, beyond the algebraic process of the cancellation, is it possible to improve the insight of it relating it with proportionality and compound ratios. Do anyone else see the bridge in a clear and compact way?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused; how would you appeal to proportionality and/or ratios without simultaneously appealing to cancellation properties of fractions?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're referring to?

Comment: @greenbagels Yes, I mean to be able to appeal to the use of fractions but being more tightly explained (or derived) with compound ratios.